# Javascript reset total

Tags: javascript

Here's my JavaScript:

```js
var total = 0,
    bonus;

function addToTotal(score) {
    total += score;
    document.getElementById("idiot").innerHTML = total;
    if (bonus) {
        total += score;
        bonus = false;
        document.getElementById("idiot").innerHTML = total;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="undo" onclick="" class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 card">
  <img src="./resources/images/undo.png">
</div>

<div id="reset" onclick="" class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 card">
  <img src="./resources/images/forest.png">
</div>

<div id="total" class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 card total">
  <h2 id="score"></h2>
  <p id="idiot"></p>
</div>
```

I didn't bother copying the rest of the HTML as it's essentially the same as above, but with each one holding a value. When clicked, that value is added to the total. There's another variable called bonus, which essentially doubles the value of whatever is clicked next.

I'm very new to JavaScript, so getting to this point was a lot of trial and error. However, I just can't figure out the next two steps.

1. Reset the total to 0 on a click.
2. Undo the last value added to the total on a click.

I know the answer is probably really simple, but all the simple things I've tried don't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: how much undo do you need?

Comment: Please post the rest of your html and javascript, it's difficult to help you from just this as many things appear to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the last values in an array and use it for assigning `total` and `bonus` values.

For resetting, you could just set `total` to zero and `bonus` to a falsy value, like `false`.

What's inside:

- an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for storing the last values of `total` and `bonus` in an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object),
- [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for adding an item to the end of the array,
- [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) for getting the last item of the array and removing it from the array.
- for every change, an object is saved with this structure

  ```
  {
      total: 0,    // or actual value
      bonus: false // or true
  }
  ```
- using of one of two [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with dot notation:

  ```
  bonus = l.bonus;
  //       ^^^^^^     dot notation

  bonus = l['bonus'];
  //       ^^^^^^^^^  bracket notation
  ```
- some minor changes, like moving

  ```
  document.getElementById("idiot").innerHTML = total;
  ```

  to the bottom of the function after changing values.

  and initializing

  ```
  bonus = false,
  ```
- at last, two new functions `reset` for resting all values to the former initalizing values and `undo`, which takes the last store object, if exists and assigns the last values to the two variables. Then update the display.

```js
var total = 0,
    bonus = false,
    last = [];

function addToTotal(score) {
    last.push({ total: total, bonus: bonus });
    total += score;
    if (bonus) {
        total += score;
        bonus = false;
    }
    document.getElementById("idiot").innerHTML = total;
}

function reset() {
    last.push({ total: total, bonus: bonus });
    bonus = false;
    total = 0;
    document.getElementById("idiot").innerHTML = total;
}

function undo() {
    var l;
    if (last.length) {
        l = last.pop();
        bonus = l.bonus;
        total = l.total;
    } else {
        bonus = false;
        total = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("idiot").innerHTML = total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Could you explain this part for me? ({ total: total, bonus: bonus })

Comment: this part creates a new object with property total (the part left from colon) with the value of `total` (right from colon) and the same for bonus.

Answer (score 0):

you can make two functions one to reset total and call that onclick event of reset div and other function to undo last add, for this you will need to store the last added value, then you can subtract this from the total in the function. This works for only 1 undo, if you want to do more undo(s) you will need to store previous additions in a list and then keep subtracting these from total, something like this:

```js
var total = 0, lastValue =[];
var bonus;

function addToTotal(score) {
total += score;
lastValue.push(score); //add score for undo in list.
document.getElementById("idiot").innerHTML = total;
if (bonus) {
    total += score;
    bonus = false;
    document.getElementById("idiot").innerHTML = total;
}
}

function resetTotal(){
  total = 0;
  lastValue =[];
  console.log(total);
}
function undoLastAdd(){
   if(lastValue.length < 1)
       return;
   total -= lastValue[lastValue.length-1]; //subtract last addition from total
   lastValue.splice(-1,1); //remove last addition from list as it has been subtracted from total
}
```

```html
    <div id="undo" onclick="undoLastAdd()" class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 card">
  <img src="./resources/images/undo.png">
  </div>

  <div id="reset" onclick="resetTotal()" class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 card">
    <img src="./resources/images/forest.png">
  </div>

  <div id="total" class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 card total">
  <h2 id="score"></h2>

  <p id="idiot"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Really appreciate this :)

Comment: I was wondering if you could explain the undo function a bit more for me? I really want the logic to stick rather than just copying the code. I understand that you're storing the last value clicked in an array, and that the lastValue.length is calling that value, but what does the '-1' part, and splice part do?

Comment: it removes the last undo value from the lastValue array, once you click undo you remove last value inside array from total. After this you must also remove it from array because it is not required anymore as you have already undid it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var total = 0,
    node = document.querySelector("#idiot"),
    bonus,
    history = []; // save the last X total(s)

function addToTotal(score) {
    // If we need to add bonus add the score twice
    history.push(total + score * (bonus ? 2 : 1))

    // and store it inside your history array
    node.innerHTML = history[history.length-1]; 

    // reset the bonus flag
    bonus = false;
    }

function reset() {
    // Clear all previous history
    history =[]

    // Clear the total
    total = 0;

    // Update the HTML 
    node.innerHTML = 0; 
}
```

```html
<div id="undo" onclick="" class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 card">
  <img src="./resources/images/undo.png">
</div>

<div id="reset" onclick="" class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 card">
  <img src="./resources/images/forest.png">
</div>

<div id="total" class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 card total">
  <h2 id="score"></h2>
  <p id="idiot"></p>
</div>
```